# Autowire a Bean in spring-boot-starter library which is not created yet | TransformerSupplier Kafka Streams

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am creating a spring-boot-starter kafka streams library.
In that I am defining a configuration class which will have a list of storeBuilders.

```
class CustomConfiguration {
    private String A;
    private String B;
    private Set<StoreBuilder<?>> transformationStoreBuilders;
    private Set<StoreBuilder<?>> processorStoreBuilders;


    // Constructor and Getter
}
```

The client which will import this spring-boot-starter library will have to create a bean of the above configuration class.

Now I am creating a custom TransformerSupplier and I want to auto-set the stores by autowiring stores from CustomConfiguration.
I am doing something like this:

```
public abstract class CustomTransformerSupplier<A, B, C, D> implements TransformerSupplier<A, B, KeyValue<C, D>> {

    @Autowired
    private CustomConfiguration configuration;

    public abstract CustomTransformer<A, B, KeyValue<C, D>> get();

    public Set<StoreBuilder<?>> stores() {
        return configuration.getTransformationStoreBuilders();
    }
}
```

However the CustomTransformerSupplier bean will be created by the client and we cannot Autowire bean in a non Bean class.

How do I auto set the store builders in the transformer supplier?

Why am I following the approach mentioned is because:

- The client can have n store builders
- There is going to be a ProcessorSupplier and a TransformerSupplier. They can share common state stores.
- I want the client to just create the state stores and not worry about injecting the state stores in the TransformerSupplier and the processorSupplier.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

See if `@Configurable` may answer to your question: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-atconfigurable